# Replace arbitrary characters in the middle of an IP address string with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to find and replace either one or two numerical characters in strings in a file.  The strings are IP addresses of the form:

```
10.xx.y.z
```

Where `xx` can be one or two characters.

I want to replace the `xx` with the single character `0`, so I have

```
10.0.y.z
```

preserving the values of `y` and `z`.

The string may appear multiple times in the file.  What is the `sed` invocation to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
n=[:digit:] o="[$n]\{1,3\}\."

sed -e"s/^/ /" \
    -e"s/\([^.$n]$o\)$o\($o${o%.})/\10.\2/g" \
    -e"s/.//" \
<in >out
```

It doesn't restrict the octets to 8bits, and it doesn't restrict the last octect to three digits, but it might be good enough.

If you want to edit the file in-place, the *best* way to do so *(as opposed to using the often dangerous `-i` switch for `perl` or some `sed`s)* is to first get a temporary copy of the file, edit it, and then to write the edited, temporary copy back over your original. Most shells *(including `bash` and `zsh`)* will get you a secure, temporary file automatically when you request a here-document:

```sh
sed -e"#...script..." \
<<IN  >infile
$(cat <infile)
IN
```

The above will drop any trailing blank lines in *`infile`* if there are any, but there are numerous other answers on this site which demonstrate how to preserve those as well, if you require it. It also does not handle null bytes, which is a harder problem to solve without `zsh`.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You just have to be careful not to make "in" and "out" the same filename, otherwise you end up with a zero-length file.  Not a good idea in any case.

Comment: @JohnHupcey - yeah, don't do that. See the edit.

Comment: Unfortunate side effect is that it not only changes 10.xx.y.z strings, but also changes netmasks like 255.255.255.0 to 255.0.255.0.  Not good!  I thought it was restricting edits to strings that began with "10." but evidently not.

Comment: @JohnHupcey - i was pretty clear about that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (as specified) that file is composed of string and string are *IP*

with 1 IP per line

```
sed 's/.[^.]*/0/' YourFile
```

With several IP per line

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}[.]\)[^.]*\(\([.][[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)\{2\}\)/\1.0\2/g' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
o="[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}"  
sed  -e"s/10\.$o\.\($o\.$o\)/10.0.\1/g" <input.txt >output.txt
```

Modifies 10.X.y.z to 10.0.y.z in any position in a file, even multiple times on the same line.  Doesn't mess with arbitrary WWW.x.y.z strings at all.